# Facebook AppRequests redirect user to a Page Tab

Tags: facebook

When sending an AppRequest using from a page Tab:

```
FB.ui({
    method  : 'apprequests',
    message : 'message',
    title   : 'Friend'
}, function (response){}));
```

I want the receiving user to be directed to the page tab and not the canvas application page.
is there a redirect_uri parameter that's no documented or should I just do a hard refresh on the canvas?

Also would like to know if I can force the user to select only one friend in this dialog in used to be possible in the old requests widget?

Thoughts appreciated

Comment: It's probably just a typo, but you seem to have one too many closing braces at the end of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user clicks 'Accept' on a Request, they will be sent to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. This URL will contain an additional GET parameter request_ids, which is a comma delimited list of Request IDs that a user is trying to act upon:

https://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]

You can the redirect to the fan page tab.

Atul Agrawal, Founder, [ascratech.com](http://ascratech.com/)

Comment: Hi. If you are an user of the app and click the appname in bookmarks, it goes by default to canvas, without request_ids parameter. Do you know some way to detect canvas and "force" redirection to AppPageUrl? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by setting up a requestCallback method, a JavaScript method that gets called after completing the dialogue.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'Requests are fun.',
          display: 'iframe',
          access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
          }, requestCallback);

  function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
        window.location = "URL_FOR_RESPONSE_ACTION";
  }
```